# Getting Azure Active Directory roles for a logged in user

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

In my .Net Core Web application, I've added a check for a view to be displayed only when an user with an "Admin" role logs in using Azure AD authentication. This is the code in Startup.cs file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));   
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();

        }
```

for the check of User role, I'm using following code:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
 {
    haveAccess = true;
 }
```

but even if I login with a user which is having other role assigned than "Admin", like "Sales", still the variable haveAccess returns true ,i.e User.IsInRole("Admin") always returns true.

Is there any other way to get roles assigned to user from Azure AD in .Net Core?